# Second highest order coefficient of ordinary differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, laplacian

Let $n$ be a natural number, $a_k(x)$ functions defined on an interval and $$Df(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(a_1(x)\frac{d}{dx}(a_2(x)\dots\frac{d}{dx}(a_{n}(x)\frac{d}{dx}f(x))\dots)$$ be an ordinary differential operator acting on functions on the interval. $D$ can be rewritten as
$$Df(x)=a_1(x)a_2(x)\dots a_{n}(x)(\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}+b(x)\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}+\text{lower order terms})f(x).$$
Is the following a correct formula
$$b(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log(a_1(x)a_2^2(x)\dots a_n^n(x))$$
for the second leading coefficient of $D$?

NOTE:
The question is motivated by a semi-discrete model for conductivity inverse boundary problem in 2D.

Comment: How do you define the trace of a differential operator?

Comment: @Hans As a coefficient of the second highest order derivative? (Normalized in OP). By analogy with trace of a matrix being the coefficient of the second highest power of the characteristic polynomial...

Comment: Trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues. An operator is the infinite dimensional extension of a matrix. The trace of a matrix naturally extends to that of an operator as the sum of the eigenvalues of the operator.

Comment: @Hans Changed the terminology in OP. The following theorem may be relevant, but doesn't provide a definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity

Comment: @Hans In the Liouville's theorem at above link the second highest coefficient of the ODO is a minus trace of a matrix depending on $x$...

Comment: The original statement masks what you are really after. The current edit clarifies the question. You do not need the theorems. It is easy to check by mathematical induction that $b(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log(a_1a_2\dots a_n)$. Note there is no power on $a_i$.

Comment: @Hans Well, $(gh)'''=g'''h+3g''h'+3g'h''+gh'''$. Lets take $a_1(x)=a_2(x)=1$, $h=f'$ and $a_3(x)=g$. Then $Df=a_3 f^{iv}+3a_3' f'''+\dots$. So, there is a coefficient and $b(x)=\log' a_3^3$. Am I making a mistake?

Comment: You are right. I was careless in algebra. But my essential point is that you can easily prove this by mathematical induction on $n$.